# Access controller method from AngularUI bootstrap modal popup

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using the AngularUI bootstrap modal popup. I am loading an aspx file into the popup by using 'iframe'. Here is the code for my popup template:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="uploadPopup">
    <div class="modal-header text-center">
        <h4>Upload file</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
       <div id='uploadProcessIndicator' class='statusInd nwAbsPos' ></div>
       <iFrame scroll="" frameborder=0 ng-src="Upload.aspx" class='uploadIFrame'>
       </iFrame>
    </div>
</script>
```

I have a method 'chkAttachmentExtension(fileName)' in my controller scope, which I am trying to call in the aspx file. This is the code for the aspx file:

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="js/ext/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function enable() {
        if (document.getElementById('AuthenticateMsg').checked == true) {
            var filepath = $("#SelectFile").val();
            var result = chkAttachmentExtension(filepath);
            if (result == true) {
                document.getElementById('btnUploadFile').disabled = false;
                $(".fileUploadButton").addClass('button1');
            }
            else if (filepath == "") {
                document.getElementById('AuthenticateMsg').checked = false;
                document.getElementById('UploadMessage').innerText = 
                                            "You have not uploaded any file.";
                $("#UploadMessage").addClass('messageColor');
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('AuthenticateMsg').checked = false;
                document.getElementById('UploadMessage').innerText = 
                           "File format not supported.The supported files 
                            are: doc,docx,gif,htm,html,jpeg,jpg,mhtml,mpp
                            ,msg,pdf,png,ppt,pptx,psd,sql,txt
                            ,vsd,xls,xlsx,xml,zip.";
                $("#UploadMessage").addClass('messageColor');
            }
        }
        else if (document.getElementById('AuthenticateMsg').checked == false) {
            document.getElementById('btnUploadFile').disabled = true;
            $(".fileUploadButton").removeClass('button1');
        }

    }
    function clearText() {
        if (document.getElementById('UploadMessage').innerText.length > 0) {
            document.getElementById('UploadMessage').innerText = "";
            document.getElementById('btnUploadFile').disabled = true;
            $(".fileUploadButton").removeClass('button1');
            document.getElementById('AuthenticateMsg').checked = false;
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('btnUploadFile').disabled = true;
            $(".fileUploadButton").removeClass('button1');
            document.getElementById('AuthenticateMsg').checked = false;
        }

    }
    function showLoadingMssg() {
        document.getElementById('UploadMessage').innerText = "Uploading...";
        $("#UploadMessage").addClass('messageColor');
        document.getElementById('btnHiddenUploadFile').click();
    }


    // ]]>
</script>
```

I am not able to access this method and get the error "chkAttachmentExtension is undefined". I tried including the controller.js in the aspx file but it again throws an error since I think it's already included once in my Home page html file.

How can i solve this?

UPDATED: 
Content of the iframe parent:

Link for image:
http://uditnarayan.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/iframeParent.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scope is attached to dom elements, so if you can get to the root element of your modal, you can call `angular.element(node).scope()` on it. The scope object should have the methods you need.

Comment: I can access the parent of iframe using javascript 'parent' object. I have attached the link for the snapshot where you can see the contents that I get for the parent of iframe. But I am not getting how can I access the scope method through that.

Comment: You wrap it in an `angular.element()` call and then call scope() on that